# Import-module speed discrepancies

Tags: powershell, windows-7, settings, powershell-5.0, import-module

I am trying to figure out why one computer takes much longer to import a custom powershell module versus another.

I have 2 computers which both have Windows 7, PowerShell version 5.0, the same folder structure, same code, same hardware specs, and the same profile.ps1 set ups. Computer A takes ~2 minutes to import the module, and computer B takes under 5 seconds.

Here are the things I have tried/checked:

1. Logging onto computer A's account with computer B. Computer B was still faster.
2. Logging onto a different account with computer A. Still slow.
3. Cross referenced the Network and Internet -> Internet Properties -> Advanced settings between computer A and B. They are the same.
4. Checked Get-ExecutionPolicy on computer A and B. They are the same.

I looked into "optimizing" the way the module gets imported in the code so computer A is faster at importing than before, but it still does not solve the issue of WHY they import at such different speeds.

Any ideas, guidance, or pointers in the right direction are greatly appreciated!
Thanks :)

Comment: [Set a breakpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/set-psbreakpoint?view=powershell-5.1) and step through it or utilize `Trace-Command`.  Is the module loaded over the network?  It almost sounds like a network issue.

Comment: Does the module do anything such as map a drive, etc (like, for example, the ActiveDirectory module)?  Touching anything external to the module (especially network-related) could cause issues like this.

Comment: @boxdog I do import the SQLServer module for the module that I speak of in the question, however even when I'm importing a custom module that references no external modules it takes much longer proportionally on computer A than computer B.

Comment: How are you importing it? (e.g. by full path, name only).  Check `$env:PSModulePath` on both machines.  The slower one may have a network location in their path.

Comment: . (Join-Path $PSScriptRoot 'exampleFile.ps1') is how I'm importing it. Both my computers have the same folder structure and the same values for $env:PSModulePath

Comment: sorry, I should've said my slowModule.psm1 file dot sources the .ps1 files using Join-Path, and when I import-module slowModule, that is the process that takes a while.